# not able to add spring security in a spring mvc application

Tags: spring-security

I added spring security to my spring application , added jars are spring security config,spring security security web and spring security core, still it is showing ' enable web security' annotation as cannot be resolved as a type.

i used `web.xml`, `applicationcontext.xml`, and `annotations`. **Now i added a new class which contains spring security annotations**.

Comment: You should really use a dependency management tool like maven, ivy or gradle where you can specify your spring security dependency like `compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.1.1.RELEASE` and all required JARs will be included.

Comment: please provide more information: relevant code fragments, project setup  etc...

Comment: i used web.xml,applicationcontext.xml,and annotations.now i added  a new class which contains spring security annotations.

Comment: please update your question (link `edit`). Don't add necassary information as comments. Look at [ask]

Comment: this is because of spring security config jar 3.0 release , i updated to 3.2 then it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of spring security config jar 3.0 release , i updated to 3.2 then it is working .